# How to write an excel index match formula with varying criteria?

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

Good day,

I have this index/match formula constructed based on a csv table i donwloaded from our office system and it's working fine:

```
IFERROR(INDEX('2nd'!$A$1:$D$100,MATCH("Enter BIN 1 Quantity",'2nd'!$B$1:$B$100,0),4),0)
```

[image]

However, I noticed that some tables i donwloaded showed different search patterns . Sometimes it's
"Enter Bin1 Qty"(no space) and there are times its just "Bin 1 Qty" or Bin1 Quantity". How can I make my formula adapt to this varying search criteria?. Your kind help will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Mike

[image: Final Table]

On this Final Table i will be displaying all the data from index matches formula. Got 2 other sheets, 1st and 2nd where I will paste the downloaded csv tables. 2nd sheet displays the 1st table image i posted here (w/c include the varying description and its equivalent value).

[image: 2nd Sheet]

Hi @OverflowStacker,  I tried your solution below but its throwing number error. Based on the above tables, here is the formula based on your solution, kindly check any problem in referencing, thanks, appreciate the help in advance (i entered it as an array as you mentioned below)

```
INDEX('2nd'!$D$2:$D$100,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX($T$2:$T$5,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($T$2:$T$5,SUBSTITUTE('2nd'!B2," ",""))),ROW($T$2:$T$5)),1)),SUBSTITUTE('2nd'!$B$2:$B$100," ",""))),ROW('2nd'!$B$2:$B$100)),1))
```

[image: helper cell]

This is where i placed the possible search strings.

Comment: Which part are you exactly looking for? Are there other combinations such as "bin1" and "quality" or is it sufficient to search for "bin1"?

Comment: Hi @OverflowStacker,i think its not enough to put :Bin 1" only since some tables also shows "Good Bin" instead.im looking for a way similar to OR function so i can declare these strings individually inside the MATCH function

Comment: i posted a sample table for reference.these description under Item Name varies.i want to have a way,similar to OR function wherein i will declare all the search criteria so that i can still get its corresponding Value

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated :). It's an Array-formula  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=INDEX($G$1:$G$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX($D$1:$D$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$4,SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))),ROW($D$1:$D$4)),1)),SUBSTITUTE($F$1:$F$4," ",""))),ROW($F$1:$F$4)),1))
```

[image]

You can create a list with search terms (here in column `D`) to get right keyword which is searched for in table 2 (columns `F:G`).

Comment: thanks a lot @OverflowStacker,i will look into this,appreciate the help

Comment: hi @OverflowStacker,i tried your solution and its throwing a number error (#NUM!).perhaps my substitution of references got issue,i posted additonal images above for reference,kindly  check where could i made the mistake,thanks

Comment: @Mike Please share a shortened workbook where the columns are as you need them. Also the complete search term needs to occur for the formula to work.

Comment: Hi @OverflowStacker i uploaded a sample workbook in this link.kindly check,thanks a lot